# How do i create a windows phone 8 app using c# in visual studio 2010?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, windows-phone-8

i am trying to create a windows mobile application which will be a native application and would like to use Visual Studio 2010 c# but however i could not find which project type to use anyone with any idea?

Comment: You can't have a [native](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Native_%28computing%29) application written in c#, as c# is compiled to run on the .NET framework.

Comment: So you're saying that i can't use C# for developing a native application? Then how do i develop a native application using Visual Studio 2010?

Comment: _Native_ code has to be written using C++, but you probably don't need native code. If you write your app using c#, you will be writing _managed_ code. See the [msdn article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj681687%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) on writing native apps for Windows Phone 8.

Comment: I think by "native" he simply meant "running on .NET" as opposed to the absolute meaning of "native".

Comment: Because currently my project is to create a Game for windows mobile probably Windows Phone 8. However, I'm not sure of which project type to choose to create the project? [Puzzle Bubble](http://www.shooter-bubble.com/puzzle-bobble.php) Trying to do a game like this, however on a mobile version.

Comment: If you're just creating a simple 2D game, the "Visual C# Windows Phone App" template is probably the best choice. For performance & 3D, you could choose to use DirectX, but it's a lot harder to use.

Comment: But i don't seem to have the "Visual C# Windows Phone App" template in my Visual Studio 2010. I'm trying to look for that template too, but i can't seem to find it. [Print Screen of my Visual Studio 2010](http://imgur.com/5S4kq2f)

Comment: You need to do as Alaa Masoud recommends below and install the SDK. [Print Screen of my Visual Studio 2010](http://i.imgur.com/b641tRS.png)

Answer (score 7):

I am assuming you mean Windows Phone not Windows Mobile. For Visual Studio 2010, you can download the [Windows Phone 7.1 SDK](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=27570). It includes all the necessary tools to develop WP 7.1 apps.

For Visual Studio 2012 you can download the [Windows Phone 8.0 SDK](https://dev.windowsphone.com/en-us/downloadsdk)